# AngularJS - How to call directive function in dynamic content from ng-bind-html?

Tags: angularjs

If you create a directive that dynamically loads HTML content, then it seems you can't call that directive's functions from that generated HTML.  My guess is that the content needs to be linked AFTER it's generated in the directive.  I try compiling the element after changing the dynamic content, but that doesn't help.  The function never gets called.  Is there a way to do this?  (Many thanks in advance!)

In the code below, you can see that there's a static call to the doIt() function from the directive's template.  That works.  But a call to the same function from within the dynamic content doesn't work.

Here's the element that invokes my directive:

```
<issue obj="obj" label="Make Dynamic Content"></issue>
```

Here's my directive:

```
(function () {
angular.module('myModule').directive('issue', function ($compile, $sce) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            label: '@',
            obj: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/docs/docs.issue.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs){

            scope.theLabel = attrs.label;

            scope.doIt = function() {
                alert("DOIT CALLED FROM WITHIN ISSUE");
            };

            scope.showIssue = function() {
                // THIS CALL TO doIt() FAILS -- NEVER GETS CALLED...
                var s = '<p>Dynamic content: <br><a href="" ng-click="doIt()">Click Me</a></p>';
                scope.obj = {content: $sce.trustAsHtml(s)};
                jQuery('#issue-panel').show();
                $compile(element)(scope);
            };
        }
    };
});
}).call(this);
```

And here's the HTML template for the directive...  {{theLabel}} will say "Make Dynamic Content".  When you click on that, it generates the dynamic content within obj.content.  I have a static call to doIt() that shows above the generated content.

```
<div id="win-container">
<a href="" ng-click="showIssue()">
    {{theLabel}}
</a>
<div id="issue-panel">
    <div class="topicWin-content">
        <!-- THIS CALL TO doIt() WORKS... -->
        <p>Static content:<br> <a href="" ng-click="doIt()">Static Click</a></p>
        <div ng-bind-html="obj.content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also tried wrapping the generated content in applyAsync() -- still no joy.

Comment: this is another in a long line of questions about how to create dynamic HTML from strings in angular.  The practice of storing HTML in strings is counter to the way that angular works, and is generally not necessary anyway.  the only reason to store HTML in strings rather than actual templates is for user generated content, which is a whole different kind of content management.

Comment: @Claies In my case, it's not necessarily about strings -- the data source could be a process, could be an API result, could be a string in a file in some other format...  The point is to integrate content in the app GUI. If the angular app is what gets the content, then if the content needs a link, that link must call the angular app. Is there something inherent in angular that says an app view shouldn't deliver textual content?

Comment: No, my point is that angular doesn't play nicely with html templates that are created as data, due to it's focus on separation of concerns.  Data is data, html is html, and storing data in html or html as data is against the problem the framework was designed to solve.

Comment: Fair enough, but the fact is I'm not storing data in html or vis versa. I'm converting data into HTML, and sometimes I want that HTML to behave like the HTML we know and love...  Click here, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can work around the problem.  I just expose the function I want to call in my directive, and then implement an arbitrary function in the template that calls the function I want.  Then my functions in the generated content just call that arbitrary function.  Technically, this isn't what I asked to do, but it gets the job done...  I can generate content, and then call my directive from within that generated content.

To call the directiveI do this -- note the func attribute:

```
<issue id="cudTest" obj="obj" func="func" label="Make Dynamic Content"></issue>
```

Then the directive looks like this:

```
(function () {
angular.module('myModule').directive('issue', function ($compile, $sce) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            label: '@',
            func: '=',
            obj: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/docs/docs.issue.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs){

            scope.obj = {};

            scope.theLabel = attrs.label;

            scope.doIt = function(s) {
                alert("DOIT CALLED FROM WITHIN ISSUE: "+s);
            };

            scope.func = scope.doIt;

            scope.showIssue = function() {
                // THIS CALL TO doIt() WORKS!!!
                var arg = "'This is a template call from dynamically generated content!'";
                var s = s+'<p>TEST content: <br><a onclick="javascript:templateCall('+arg+')">TEST Click Me 2!</a></p>';
                scope.obj.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(s);
                jQuery('#issue-panel').show();
            };
        }
    };
});
}).call(this);
```

And finally, the template looks like this...  I can be more clever about finding the directive element, but for this I'm using an ID:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var templateCall = function(s) {
    var thisElem = document.getElementById("cudTest");
    var myScope = angular.element(thisElem).scope();
    myScope.$apply(function() {
        myScope.func(s);
    });
}
</script>

<a href="" ng-click="showIssue()">{{theLabel}}</a>
<!-- THIS CALL TO doIt() WORKS... -->
<p>Static content:<br>
<a ng-click="doIt('This is a static call')">Static Click</a></p>
<div ng-bind-html="obj.content"></div>
```